# Maximal ideal space of  $C^*$-algebra of Riemann integrable functions

Tags: reference-request, c-star-algebras, ideals

Let $R([0,1])$ be the unital commutative $C^*$-algebra of complex valued Riemann integrable functions on $[0,1]$ with pointwise operations and the supremum norm.

In the 1980 paper *The Gelfand space of the Banach algebra of Riemann integrable functions* by Jörg Blatter (MR0602719) the author states, that no satisfactory representation is known for the space of maximal ideals of $R([0,1])$.

For the smaller space of [regulated functions](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regulated_function) on $[0,1]$ the maximal ideal space consists of the functionals $\beta_x,\delta_x, \gamma_x$ given by $\beta_x(f)=f(x)$, $\delta_x(f)=\lim_{y\to x^+}f(y)$ and $\gamma_x(f)=\lim_{y\to x^-}f(y)$ where $x\in [0,1]$, see e.g. *The character space of the algebra of regulated functions* by S. K. Berberian (MR0487932).

I wonder whether some progress has been made concerning the maximal ideal space of $R([0,1])$ since Blatter's paper. In fact I would be very thankful if someone could provide me with an example of a character on $R([0,1])$ which is *not* of the form $\beta_x$, $\delta_x$, $\gamma_x$ as above or some intuition why the determination of the maximal ideal space of $R([0,1])$ is so much harder than the corresponding problem for the space of regulated functions.

Comment: lvb, just a remark: your last sentence seems to imply that the characters $\beta_x$, $\delta_x$, $\gamma_x$ extend to $R([0,1])$ which I don't think they do. By the way, what's the topology on $[0,1]\sqcup [0,1]\sqcup [0,1]$ regarded as the promitive ideal space of the regulated functions?

Comment: In fact *every* maximal ideal of R is an extension of one of $\beta_x$, $\delta_x$, $\gamma_x$. It's just that they do not extend in a unique way. You can construct the maximal ideals via ultrafilters.

Comment: Thank you. You are right. I should have seen that. Do you know a reference where this construction is carried out?

Comment: lvb, if you want to make sure that George Lowther notices your comment, use @George Lowther.

Comment: lvb, I think it's an interesting question. A simple remark
is that $R([0,1])$ is a non-separable Banach space.
Similarly, the complex Banach space $l^\infty ([0,1])$ is also
non-separable. Can one find a concrete maximal ideal of
$l^\infty ([0,1])$ ? I don't know. (supplementary question) David Bernier

Comment: @David: As a new user with < 50 rep, you are unable to leave comments. However, as your post was really a comment rather than an actual answer to the question, I manually converted it into a comment. You will soon have enough rep to leave comments directly yourself.

Comment: May be his can help you. Consider algebra of sets $\Sigma=\{E\subset[0,1]: \lambda(\operatorname{int}(E))=\lambda(\operatorname{cl}(E))\}$. Then $L_\infty([0,1],\Sigma,\lambda|_\Sigma)$ is isomorphic to the space Riemann integrable functions with $\sup$-norm. (see exercise 363Yi in Measure theory D. H. Fremlin Vol 3)